# How to ensure timer records at fixed interval?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to create a windows phone application that records the accelerometer data at 100 Hz. I tried out both `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` and `System.Threading.Timer`, but looking at the data recorded, neither were actually recording at 100 Hz. `DispatcherTimer` records 60-80 Hz, while `Timer` records at around 85-90 Hz. I don't think the problem is the phone not being able to handle it, since when I tried recording at 50 Hz, it was still lagging to only 40+ Hz. Here is a snippet of my code:

For `DispatcherTimer`:

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
```

For `Timer`:

```
timer = new Timer(timer_Tick, null, 0, 10);
```

How do I make sure that I am recording at a fixed rate interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 -  is not a [real-time OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system). None of the timer classes are exactly precise. All you're doing it saying that you want to wait at least this long. It takes some amount of time for everything to fire and you to end up notified that the timer has ticked once OS gets around to actually servicing the tick message. 
Try to implement simple test: Print current time every 10 milliseconds, and you can see minimum error. When developers use `1` or `5` or `10` seconds like interval - this is not noticeable.